# Imprime tag <b> Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am a newbie in Jquery. I need that el method text() imprimes  the tag  in bold within the div2 , no only the text

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#div1").text("Text: " + $("#test").text());
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#div2").text("HTML: " + $("#test").html());
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="test">This is some <b>bold</b> text in a paragraph.</p>
<button id="btn1">Show Text</button>
<button id="btn2">Show HTML</button>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is the following. I don't want `<b>bold</b>` , but the text in bold

```
HTML: This is some <b>bold</b> text in a paragraph.
```

Comment: you need to call `html` instead of `text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$('#div1').html("This is some <b>bold</b> text in a paragraph.");
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Pardon for the question. I am really a newbie

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#div1").text("Text: " + $("#test").html());
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#div2").html("HTML: " + $("#test").html());
  });
```

here is demo http://jsfiddle.net/r1cj52ds/1/

jQuery **.text()**: Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.  http://api.jquery.com/text/

jQuery **.html()**: Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element. http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 1):

use below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#div1").html("Text: " + $("#test").text());
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#div2").html("HTML: " + $("#test").html());
  });
});
```